# facebook api graph, get public photos

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, photos

I want to know if using the graph api there is a way to get all the public photo (or at least a limited list) stored in facebook, i know that you can get the public post using a keyword with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=keyword&type=post
```

Is there a photo equivalent way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL to query for all the photos in the user's news feed. [This post](http://pulkitgoyal.in/2012/12/26/getting-all-photos-and-videos-from-facebook-news-feed/) discusses this in some detail. Here is the FQL that you could use:

```
SELECT actor_id, created_time, likes, post_id, attachment 
FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN ( 
    SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND (name = "Photos")
)
```

Comment: which user this method explore?

Comment: It finds photos in the news feed of currently authorized user.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i want to find the pubblic photos of all facebook users.

Comment: @PhantomFav As far as I know, there isn't a way to pull publicly posted content from Facebook through their Graph API. I'm still searching though...and waiting.